# Unable to delete uploaded XML file on Drupal 8.5

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-8

I have created a media type that accepts XML files and saves them to a custom publicly accessible location on the server.

Ideally I would like the file to be overwritten when the exact same file is uploaded. This does not happen, instead it creates a new file and adds a number on the end. I have "Create new Revision" turned off.

To get around this issue I thought I could just delete the file via the CMS. The uploaded file has status of "Permanent" and is used 0 places. I know the cron job cleans up files for you, but when I run the cron the file in question is still there. I figure it's because the file is set to permanent, but I don't see a way to flip this to temporary.

Any help is much appeciated.

Comment: For others with similar deletion issues in Drupal 8. I decided to use https://www.drupal.org/project/imce extension. It provides a file manager view and actually works. My previous comment below is also a solution but has rights issues with multiple user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting nested away in the file system settings, which lets you configure it to remove (or not removed) orphaned files. If drush isn't removing them despite having no usages recorded, I'd check this option isn't ticked.

The temporary and permanent status are used for storing temporary files during the upload/save process, so I wouldn't tinker with those too much.

If you fancy making the form yourself using the form API, then you can save the file programmatically using the FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE parameter.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_save_data/8.5.x

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end I decided to use a extension since everything I tried didn't work and I was in a hurry. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations